# UITableViewController -UISearchBar should not scroll with tableview when in tableViews.tableHeaderView. as Note.app

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have got similar issue with `UITableView` with a `UISearchBar` using storyborad as the

`tableViews.tableHeaderView.  [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,40)];`

worked for me too.  But the problem is,I don't want `UISearchBar` to scroll along with `tableview` as in Note.app. Can anyone suggest me how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a header view. Instead, add the search bar as a subview as the table view superview so it's a sibling.

---

If you're using `UITableViewController`, change to use `UIViewController` instead. The only things you need to do are:

1. Change the superclass
2. Add the delegate and datasource protocol definitions to the `@interface`
3. Change the XIB so the table view is a subview of a normal view
4. Add a property `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView` and connect it in the XIB

Comment: In UITableViewController, we have only option to add UISearchbar in header.